# How can I change a function argument into a variable?

Tags: ruby

Here is my code currently:

```
def name_grabber(name)
    puts "What is your #{name} name?"
    print "> "
    $name = gets.chomp
    print $name
end

name_grabber("first")
name_grabber("middle")
name_grabber("last")

puts "Nice to meet you, #{first} #{middle} #{last}"
puts
```

I want it so I can but first as a string into name_grabber and then first become a variable I can use later.

Using Ruby 2.0.0

Comment: use `@name`..instead `$name`..

Comment: not an answer,, a suggestion...

Comment: he wants the variable input string to become the variable name returned by the function, similar to how php uses $$var;

Comment: @ArupRakshit it was directed to OP (I am not the OP).

Comment: @user3477950 Mistake with *user..* :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
def name_grabber(name)
    puts "What is your #{name} name?"
    print "> "
    gets.chomp
end

first = name_grabber("first")
middle = name_grabber("middle")
last = name_grabber("last")

puts "Nice to meet you, #{first} #{middle} #{last}"
puts
```

Comment: what is last `puts` ?

Comment: @Arup - Copied it from OP code - changed the minimum